# accessing script level functions inside member functions

Tags: python, jython

I have a jython script where in a class is defined with some member functions. In the script there are other functions defined too:

```
    import xxxx
    class SomeClass  (Callable):
        def call(self):
            hello()

    def hello():
        print 'hello'        

    ldr_files = []
    ldr_files.append(SomeClass())
    thread_pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8)
    results = thread_pool.invokeAll(ldr_files)
```

However, this doesn't seem to agree with jython and it does not call the 'hello()' function.

There a bunch of other member function - member function calls etc that are called before calling hello() which work fine. It is only when the control moves to that call, it doesn't seem to call the function (no hello printed).

Comment: How are you calling foo? Also, your syntax looks off,  `class SomeClass` should be `class SomeClass:`.

Comment: Thanks @kennes913. edit made. SomeClass is a dummy representation. I actually have a callable that is used by a threadpoolexecutor. To keep things simple, i have represented them as above.

Comment: To answer the question, foo() is called by instantiating SomeClass down the script and calling the method on top of it.

Comment: Like so? `class_instance = SomeClass()` , `class_instance.foo()`

Comment: Do you have another `hello` (or whatever it is actually called) function somewhere? Maybe you are importing another one. Are you imports like `from foo import *`?

Comment: Updated the code to resemble actual scenario

Comment: There is only 1 hello

Comment: are you sure `SomeClass().call()` is being invoked. Can you put a print statement directly in it?

Comment: And you pass your class instance to some concurrent pool. Big chance function `hello` goes out of scope, and `call` cant find it. And you don't see an error because the new threat has no access to stderr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the parameters being passed in the actual code. Spelling mistake ! So much for an editor that wouldn't show it to me.

Apologies for the time wasted.